# Starting gpg-agent with specific options

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I have an application, run as a service by a system user, which uses GPG (using libgpgme in C).  This user has no home directory and I would like to eliminate password caching.

Therefore I'd like `gpg-agent` to be started with `--homedir=/opt/myapp/.gnupg --default-cache-ttl 0`.

`gpg-agent(1)` says:

> The agent is automatically started on demand by gpg, gpgsm, gpgconf, or gpg-connect-agent.  Thus  there  is
> no  reason to start it manually.

This leads me to a few of questions:

1. How should one start `gpg-agent` for a specific home-dir with specific command-line options?
2. If `gpg-agent` is already running, is it possible to change the `homedir`/`default-cache-ttl` or should I kill the existing agent?
3. Will killing the existing `gpg-agent` affect other (non-system) users?

---

For question1: `gpg-connect-agent --homedir /opt/myapp/.gnupg /bye` creates a new `gpg-agent` with that homedir, but any other agents continue to run.  Which `gpg-agent` will be used when we sign?

For question 2: I tried the following. However, `homedir` does not appear as an option in `--list-options gpg-agent` and while I saw the new values refresh during `--list-options`, I was still able to sign files without a password.

```
echo "default-cache-ttl::0" | gpgconf --change-options gpg-agent
echo "max-cache-ttl::0" | gpgconf --change-options gpg-agent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should one start gpg-agent for a specific home-dir with specific command-line options?

In the service file use `Environment=GNUPGHOME=/opt/myapp/.gnupg`.  `gpg-agent` is started automatically when calling `gpg` (or using necessary functions in `libgpgme`).  By setting `$GNUPGHOME`, the `gpg`/`gpgme` calls will connect to an existing `gpg-agent` with `--homedir=/opt/myapp/.gnupg` or spawn a new `gpg-agent` if a suitable one doesn't exist already.

> If gpg-agent is already running, is it possible to change the [...]default-cache-ttl or should I kill the existing agent?

From `gpgconf(1)`: "The  gpgconf  is a utility to automatically and reasonable safely query and modify configuration files in the ‘.gnupg’ home directory.  It is designed not to be invoked manually by the user..."

All you really need to do to set the `default-cache-ttl` is ensure that `$GNUPGHOME/gpg-agent.conf` exists and contains  `default-cache-ttl 0`.  Note that this needs to exist before the new instance of `gpg-agent` is created.  Therefore either ensure this file is installed with the application, or since this is a service use `ExecStartPre=` to run something that sets this.

> Will killing the existing gpg-agent affect other (non-system) users?

There should be no need to kill `gpg-agent`.  Since this is run in a service, any spawned `gpg-agent`s are isolated to the service's cgroup. When the service is stopped, spawned `gpg-agent`s will be killed by systemd.

Note: I am only reasonably sure about the paragraph above.  I noticed that when I was testing `gpg-connect-agent` in `ExecStartPre=` systemd gave a warning that `gpg-agent` still existed in the cgroup and was killed.